# Merge objects in an array that have two of the same key value pairs

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to merge objects within an array that have two of the same key value pairs. For example,

```
var ingredients = [
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: large},
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: large},
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: tbsp},
 {name: 'bacon',qty: 1,msr: cup}
];
```

Desired result:

```
ingredients = [
 {name: 'egg',qty: 6,msr: large},
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: tbsp},
 {name: 'bacon',qty: 1,msr: cup}
];
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: please add the code, you tried.

Comment: Where is another object ? Please show your code

Comment: You should use `array.reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combine with [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) to build your new array.

I would check your object exist or not by `name` and `msr`.

See my example

```js
var ingredients = [
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'large'},
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'large'},
 {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'tbsp'},
 {name: 'bacon',qty: 1,msr: 'cup'}
];

result = ingredients.reduce((acc, el) => {
  var existEl = acc.find(e => e.name == el.name && e.msr == el.msr);
  
  if (existEl) {
    existEl.qty = existEl.qty + el.qty;
  } else {
    acc.push(el);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Create an object with keys with which you could add quantities  `array#forEach`
2. Create an ans array by iterating over the object

   ```js
   var ingredients = [
    {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'large'},
    {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'large'},
    {name: 'egg',qty: 3,msr: 'tbsp'},
    {name: 'bacon',qty: 1,msr: 'cup'}
   ];

   var obj = {};
   ingredients.forEach(function (v,i) {
     var key = v.name + ' '+v.msr;
     if(!obj[key]) {
       obj[key] = +v.qty;
     } else {
       obj[key] += +v.qty;
     }
   });

   //console.log(obj);
   var ans = [];
   for(var key in obj) {
     var s = key.split(' ');
     ans.push({name:s[0], qty:obj[key], msr:s[1]});
   }
   console.log(ans);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as closure and joint the wanted values as key. Then build, if necessary a new object and later adjust the quantity.

```js
var ingredients = [{ name: 'egg', qty: 3, msr: 'large' }, { name: 'egg', qty: 3, msr: 'large' }, { name: 'egg', qty: 3, msr: 'tbsp' }, { name: 'bacon', qty: 1, msr: 'cup' }];

ingredients = ingredients.reduce(function (hash) {
    return function (r, o) {
        var key = ['name', 'msr'].map(function (k) { return o[k]; }).join('|');
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = { name: o.name, msr: o.msr, qty: 0 };
            r.push(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].qty += o.qty;
        return r;
     };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(ingredients);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```